# where the function `interpolate` is coming from

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I learning react native animation. when i `console.log(this.position.x);` it shows that the function name under `x` is `_interpolation` so why do we do :

```
transform: [{
          rotate: this.position.x.interpolate({
            inputRange: [-200, 200],
            outputRange: ['-45deg', '45deg']  // 0 : 150, 0.5 : 75, 1 : 0
          }),
        }],
```

souldn't it be:

```
transform: [{
          rotate: this.position.x._interpolation({
            inputRange: [-200, 200],
            outputRange: ['-45deg', '45deg']  // 0 : 150, 0.5 : 75, 1 : 0
          }),
        }],
```

P.S. `position` come from `this.position = new Animated.ValueXY();`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Prefixing a property with `_` usually indicates a private/internal property that should not be accessed externally. So the answer to your question is: **no**.

Also, `_interpolation` seems to be a property of an object "inside" `this.position.x` (i.e. a property of a property ...) so accessing it on `this.position.x` wouldn't work anyway.

> where the function `interpolate` is coming from

It's probably defined on the prototype of the `AnimatedValue` instance. If you don't know how prototypes work in JavaScript, I suggest to have a look at [YDKJS -
 this & object prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes).

Comment: thanks for your help, where that AnimatedValue is coming from?

Comment: Your screenshot shows that the value is an instance of `AnimatedValue`.

Comment: Here is a link to the source code of `AnimatedValue`: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1e8f3b11027fe0a7514b4fc97d0798d3c64bc895/Libraries/Animated/src/nodes/AnimatedValue.js